# element can only drop into the parent element (child element) (Jquery Sortable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Javascript :

```
$(function  () {
      $("ol.example").sortable({
    group: '.example'
  });
});
```

Demo & Complete Code : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/x0q81hfq/3/

I take from here : https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#connected

If : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Woi4.jpg, It's true

If : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdBNO.jpg, It's false

So, when a customer element drag to room type element, automatic customer element drop into the room type element.

How to make it?
Can it?

Thank you

Comment: what you want .. its already working as per your requirement

Comment: @Yo Yo, I want to limit the drag / drop like this : http://imgur.com/wIFwON3

Comment: actually your approach is wrong ,,,you are doing sortable method You should have used `jquery-ui` `Draggable` and `Droppable` ... it would have been very easy using `containment` or `revert`

Comment: @Yo Yo, http://jqueryui.com/sortable/. Jquery ui sortable is no nested list. It does not fit with my case

Comment: but you are already using sortable

Comment: @Yo Yo, Jquery sortable and jquery ui sortable. It's different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100631/discussion-between-moses-toh-and-yo-yo).